# unable to install usbserial driver for GPRS shield with mac air vs. 10.9

Tags: serial, usb, ftdi

Despite all my efforts and web crawling I can not install the necessary driver to connect my Arduino uno R3 to the GPRS shield from seeedstudio. I have attempted downloading the VCP driver from http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm 
I have tried the solution offered here https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ftdi-drivers/mac for Yosemite and beyond through the AppleUSBFTDI driver as well as the solution offered by FTDI's script. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: Shields do not require PC/Mac drivers.

Comment: in order to use the GPRS shield you must be able to connect through the /dev/tty.usbserial#### port which requires a driver.

Comment: No.  The USB serial connection is provided by the Arduino, not the shield, and the naming pattern for an Uno on OSX will *not* be tty.usbserial### but rather something else (tty.usbmodem### perhaps?).  IIRC an Uno does not require a driver on OSX though older/unofficial FTDI based boards do.

Answer (score 1):

The USB serial connection is provided by the Arduino, not the shield, and the naming pattern for an Uno on OSX will not be tty.usbserial### but rather something else (tty.usbmodem### perhaps?).

If I recall correctly, an Uno does not require a driver on OSX though older/unofficial FTDI based boards (as well as unofficial boards based on yet other fixed function chips) do require drivers.

(On Linux it is typically /dev/ttyUSB# for fixed function and /dev/ttyACM# for an Uno, both using kernel module drivers shipped with most distributions.  On Windows they are all COM# and drivers are typically required)